# Vitejs - Generate assets under subdirectories when using a multi page app

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm following the guide on vite.js for multi-pages (https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app). My goal is to have two separate pages that will be uploaded to two different domains. That means they will have different assets but share certain things in common.

The output of vitejs is currently this:

```
dist/assets/react.35ef61ed.svg   4.03 KiB
dist/app/index.html              0.52 KiB
dist/assets/app.19905cea.js      1.57 KiB / gzip: 0.80 KiB
dist/assets/index.3fce1f81.css   1.37 KiB / gzip: 0.71 KiB
dist/assets/vendor.8e3c0d1e.js   139.07 KiB / gzip: 44.74 KiB
```

For my purposes, it makes more sense to look like this:

```
dist/app/assets/react.35ef61ed.svg   4.03 KiB
dist/app/index.html                  0.52 KiB
dist/app/assets/app.19905cea.js      1.57 KiB / gzip: 0.80 KiB
dist/app/assets/index.3fce1f81.css   1.37 KiB / gzip: 0.71 KiB
dist/app/assets/vendor.8e3c0d1e.js   139.07 KiB / gzip: 44.74 KiB
```

How can I do this?

My vite.config.ts:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), splitVendorChunkPlugin()],
    build: {
            rollupOptions: {
                input: {
                    app: resolve(__dirname, './app/index.html'),
                }
            }
        }
})
```

Comment: Relevant issue in vite repo - https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12203